# How to pre-load Here Maps on a Windows UWP App using JS library?

Tags: here-api

I am creating a UWP (Universal Windows Platform) surface-pro application and need to use Here Maps. I am using the javascript library from Here Maps to display the maps.

How can I pre-load the maps using javascript library from Here Maps like the way we can pre-load the maps in Android and iOS SDKs?

Answer (score 0):

The offline map is only supported by the SDKs - Android and iOS. Within the JavaScript API this is not supported. Or you try to set up a kind of caching mechanism yourself in your Windows App.